# How to know what select is submitted in a form if i have two

Tags: php, html

I have a form with two select field. The select use onChange="form1.submit()" to submit form. And how I know what select field in the form is selected by user? I have tried to do this with two Submit Button and I can know what button have submitted easily.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["select"])) {
        echo "submit";
    }
if(isset($_POST["select2"])) {
        echo "submit2";
    }   

?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">

<select name="select" id="select" onChange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="1">Select a</option>
  <option value="1">Select b</option>

</select>
<select name="select2" id="select" onChange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="2">Select2 a</option>
  <option value="2">Select2 b</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: There is a little problem. You have two select fields with the same ID. change the ID to an `identifier` and use them for identifying your fields.

Comment: But what is not working in your code? It seems right. Are you having specific problem?

Comment: The 2nd one: In your code snippet, `isset` returns true for both fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the `<select>` values are sent to the server. What you **need** to check is for their emptiness. So kindly change your code to:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["select"])) {
  echo "submit";
}
if(!empty($_POST["select2"])) {
  echo "submit2";
}
?>
```

I do believe you should change the `value` of the select too, here:

Select a
  Select b 


  Select2 a 
  Select2 b

Generally, to check what's happening / getting posted to the code, you can do it in two ways:

**PHP Way**

Use `var_dump()` to check what has been submitted. The best one would be:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

**Network Tab**

If you are using Chrome or Firebug, you can use the Developer Tools' Network tab to check the FORM Data.

***Firebug***

[image]

***Chrome***

[image]

**Unrelated Note:** You have `<select>` tags with same `id`, which is totally wrong, but that doesn't affect it. Checking using the PHP way, will work for you.

Comment: Sorry this is not an answer to this specific question.

Comment: @Andrey I have updated more. What else would you expect?

Comment: @Andrey I am happy to change the answer to suit the right needs. Let me know if I need to add more?

Comment: @Andrey The funny part is, you don't penalize the person asking the wrong question, but you do to the person, with good intentions, taking strains to answer the question. What a world!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't penalize anyone, just express my disagreement. His code is correct in getting data out of post var. Your answer is about how to get things that were submitted (which he does already). His problem is how to distinguish which one was selected because both get posted.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for letting me know. I am gonna change my answer inline with your comments. Will you remove your downvote?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default value, such as an empty string:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST["select"])) {
        echo "submit";
    } elseif(!empty($_POST["select2"])) {
        echo "submit2";
    }  
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">

<select name="select" id="select" onChange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1a">Select a</option>
  <option value="1b">Select b</option>

</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2" onChange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="2a">Select2 a</option>
  <option value="2b">Select2 b</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

**Your HTML (Adding one more option with 0 value):**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<select name="select" id="select" onChange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Select a</option>
  <option value="1">Select b</option>    
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select" onChange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="2">Select2 a</option>
  <option value="2">Select2 b</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**Your PHP Code:**

```
if($_POST['select'] > 0){
    echo "submit";
}
if($_POST['select2'] > 0){
    echo "submit2";
}
```